# Visual Studio 2019 Collection editor not working (Black window)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I've freshly installed Visual Studio 2019 Community to do some mobile development (Xamarin.Forms)

The problem is that the collection editor is shown as a black window as demonstrating in the image below :

[Visual Studio 2019 - Collection Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlBJB.png)

I've restarted VS so many times, and changed the Theme hoping it's a problem with the theme, but no luck.

Comment: ,According to your screenshot, I guess that you want to add some toolbar items for contentpage? I try to go to **ContentPage ToolbarItems collection editor window**, it work fine and don't appear black window, so I suggest you can use code to add toolbar item to see if it works fine, or you can update visual studio.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT And where can I find this "ContentPage ToolbarItems collection editor window" ?

Comment: Click the mouse cursor in ContentPage, then you can find ToolbarItems property for ContentPage, like your screenshot.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT are we talking about the same Visual Studio 2019 Community (Xamarin.Forms) ?? there's only one Collection Editor, and it doesn't work ? May be you can give us a screenshot ?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, but I think it is the same for contentPage's Toolbaritems Collection Editor.

Comment: This is my screenshot: https://github.com/CherryBu/gif